# How to secure vinyl post caps?

Tags: deck, adhesive, vinyl

I have a deck with vinyl posts, and 5"x5" vinyl caps on the posts.  I'm looking at how I can affix them to the posts so they don't blow off.  I found a "Vinyl Fence Glue" listed at both Home Depot and Lowe's websites, but they are listed as online-only.  Amazon has something similar but it is not in stock.

Am I just looking for anything labeled as a "vinyl adhesive"?  Since it's going to be outside facing the weather, should I be aware of any qualities to avoid in an adhesive?  Would something like Gorilla Glue work?  Most "vinyl adhesive" searches end up with a bunch of the canned stuff you brush on but I think I'm looking for some sort of tubed type of adhesive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use clear silicone caulk, super strong as an adhesive when cured and waterproof.

Comment: I would also try silicone method. Still removable if you really need to. But should keep them on reasonably well. I would not say it is *super* strong though.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I'd be inclined to drive a pair of small screws, so I could remove and replace the cap if that ever becomes necessary.

If you insist on a chemical weld, I would bet that the glues used for PVC plumbing would work. Might be intolerably messy, though.

Comment: +1 for hardware.  I don't actually know the reason why but I've never seen caps applied with adhesive , always with screws.  Just make sure it's stainless or you'll have rusty stains running down your posts.

Answer (score 2):

Vinyl fence cement is [available from Lowes stores](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Freedom-Clear-Epoxy-Adhesive/3160615). I used it to attach my fence post caps.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea. Fasten a piece of line to the inside center of each cap with PVC cement and attach a three pound weight weight to the end of the line (you could use a rock I'm a pouch). Then lower the weight into the fence post and the cap can be put back on. This would not be messy, and would allow for easy access if necessary.

Thinking out of the box.

Comment: This would be great unless the post is a decorative PVC sleeve over a solid wood post.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the cap may fit on ok ,but it's  sorta loose . The easiest way to make it snuck is use some Velcro. Put 2 to 4 small pieces inside the side of the post cap to tighten the radius . The Velcro can be on either side of the strip . Sometimes the softer material makes less of a expansion then the harder side of the Velcro . Just play around with the Velcro . You can also use some Duck tape ,again sticky side down inside post cap to tighten the expansion, just a bit .You will now have enough staying strength in high winds and changing the post cap for any reason is not a issue .  Hope this helps ...

Answer (score 0):

I removed half of the post caps on the railing of my deck of my new-to-me house, and found the ones with silicone caulk (clear) held best. I tried the PVC adhesive, but it didn't work, at all.

Answer (score 0):

I used rubber bands. Put the medium width bands around the uncapped post near the very top then push the caps back on. It makes a very tight seal. No unsightly screws and no adhesive that might be difficult to remove if you need to. Not sure how long they will last but they should be sheltered from the elements.